# autohotkey: go to a specific place in a line

Tags: autohotkey

I have a long mermaid code line like

`A("hello world, this is a really long sentence that needs editing"):::test %% here are some commments about the line`

I'm editing this in obsidian and I want to go to the end of the `)` to change the `:::test` to something else.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to press use AHK to press a key that will take my cursor to after the `)`. Right now, I can press `end` and go back wards, or ctrl arrow, both options suck when the code line is really long and the `)` is right in the middle.

can AHK do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

this works in obsidian, probably works in most apps

```
!\::
    Send {home}
    Send ^f
    Send )
    Send {esc}{esc}
    return
```